# Mongoose does not updating document

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I tried searching everywhere but I always got either an error or nothing changed.
here is my code:

```js
Blog.findOneAndUpdate({title: "Lol"}, {$push: {details:"detail"}})
.then(function(){
    console.log("Data updated");
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

If anyone can advise me, I will be really happy. I still need to do the removal from the document and add / update to the document.

(Sorry for the English ... google translator)

Comment: findOneAndUpdate is asynchronous, where do you `await` it?

Comment: hmmmm maybe thats a problem

Answer (score 0):

This is async await version:

upsert: false (DO NOT create a new document if no document match filter)

new: true (return updated document if any)

```js
let filter = { title: "Lol" };
let update = { $push: { details: "detail" } };
let options = { upsert: false, new: true };
//
try {
  let updated = await Blob.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, options).exec();
  console.log(updated);
} catch (error) {
  //handle error here
}
```